# CSS: How to position elements in ng-for loop using position : "fixed"

Tags: css, angularjs, angular

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style: none">
        <li *ngFor = "#el of dragZoneElems; #idx = index">
            <h4 style = "position: fixed; top : 'idx'* 10" [dragResponder] = "el">{{el.first}} {{el.last}}</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I need the position to be fixed for the h4 elements and still order them top down. I am creating a drag directive that requires these elements to have position fixed in order to be dragged. How can I achieve this. The above code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Relevant Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/K7iR72KW9edUcIhDZozP?p=preview)

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style: none">
   <li *ngFor = "#el of dragZoneElems; #idx = index">
          <h4 [style.position]="'fixed'" [style.top.px]="idx*10" [dragResponder] = "el">{{el.first}} {{el.last}}</h4>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngStyle`

```html
<h4 [ngStyle]="{'position': 'fixed', 'top' : 'idx'* 10}" > ... </h4>
```

or

```html
<h4 [style.position]="'fixed'" [style.top]="'idx'* 10" > ... </h4>
```